# Edit SQLite data when clicking textview

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I want to update data from an SQLite database by clicking on a dynamically created textview. My database shows the name, start date, and end date of a school Term. Each textview shows the data of one School Term. When I click the ID Textview I want to go to a different screen where the user can edit the data of that particular Term. The problem is I don't know how to connect a textview to a Term ID. The textviews are dynamically created. When clicking the ID textview of a term the user goes to a new screen where she can edit the existing data. However, the EditText values only show the last Term because SetText overwrites the Terms from before. If I use append both ID's are filled in in the EditText. I only want one Term's data displayed on the edit screen and I want the Term that corresponds to the Textview ID that the user clicks. This is the code where the user clicks on the Term they want to edit. The ID Textview has onclickListeners that take the user to the next screen where the EditText's are filled with the selected Term data (that's how it's SUPPOSED to work)
[First block of code shows the first screen where the user clicks on the textvew that shows the id of each term](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RgVQ5.jpg)

```
public void ViewAll() {
                         Cursor res = myDb.getAllData();
        if(res.getCount() == 0) {
                             showMessage("Error", "Nothing Found");
                             return;
                        }
                       StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                         while(res.moveToNext()) {
                             final LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout ) findViewById(R.id.LinearLayOut);
                             final TextView textView1 = new TextView(this);
                             final TextView textView2 = new TextView(this);
                             final TextView textView3 = new TextView(this);
                             final TextView textView4 = new TextView(this);
                             textView1.append(res.getInt(0)+"\n");
                             textView2.append("Term Title : "+ res.getString(1)+"\n");
                             textView3.append("Start Date : "+ res.getString(2)+"\n");
                             textView4.append("End Date : "+ res.getString(3)+"\n");
                             textView1.setOnClickListener(
                                   new View.OnClickListener() {
                                         @Override
                                         public void onClick(View v) {
                                             Intent myIntent = new Intent(ListTerms.this, EditTerms.class);
                                             startActivity(myIntent);
                                         }
                                     }
                             );
                             layout.addView(textView1);
                             layout.addView(textView2);
                             layout.addView(textView3);
                             layout.addView(textView4);
                             }
    }      public void onClick(View v) {
                                             Intent myIntent = new Intent(ListTerms.this, EditTerms.class);
                                             startActivity(myIntent);
                                         }
                                     }
                             );
                             layout.addView(textView1);
                             layout.addView(textView2);
                             layout.addView(textView3);
                             layout.addView(textView4);
                             }
```

```
public void UpdateData() {
        saveTermInfoBtn.setOnClickListener(
                    new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            boolean isUpdate = myDb.updateTerm(termId.getText().toString(), inputTerm.getText().toString(), inputStart.getText().toString(), inputEnd.getText().toString());
                            if (isUpdate == true) {
                                Toast.makeText(EditTerms.this, "Data Update", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(EditTerms.this, "Data Not Updated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }
                    }
            );
        }
    public void ViewAll() {
                        Cursor res = myDb.getAllData();
                        if(res.getCount() == 0) {
                            // show message
                            showMessage("Error","Nothing found");
                            return;
                        }
                        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                        while (res.moveToNext()) {
                                termId.setText(res.getString(0) + "\n");
                                inputTerm.setText(res.getString(1) + "\n");
                                inputStart.setText(res.getString(2) + "\n");
                                inputEnd.setText(res.getString(3) + "\n\n");
                                 }
                        // Show all data
                        showMessage("Data",buffer.toString());
    }
```

[If I use setText only the data of the last term gets displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKqtX.jpg)
[If I use append the data of all the terms gets displayed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k0Dz9.jpg)

Comment: why don't use listView instead ?

Comment: I'm struggling to understand the problem - is it caused by the fact you're using dynamically generated `TextView`s, and so you can't reference them by id because they don't have one?

Comment: those `TextView` should indeed be fields, for example of a `CardView`... one would either need to completely unwrap the code - or at least use `.setTag()` and `.getTag()`, in order to have some kind of identification, for each of these `LinearLayout`. using `BaseAdapter` or `RecyclerView.Adapter` suggested (where one can obtain an ID, by the current item position). those `\n` are also quite useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that this does what you want (rather than update a row it Toast's the id column, which can then be passed via the intent and the data extracted).

It utilises the **tag** of each TextView to store the respective **id**

The DatabaseHelper used **DatabaseHelper.java** :-

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DBNAME = "school.db";
    public static final int DBVERSION = 1;

    public static final String TBL_TERM = "term";
    public static final String COL_TERM_ID = BaseColumns._ID;
    public static final String COL_TERM_TITLE = "title";
    public static final String COL_TERM_STARTDATE = "startdate";
    public static final String COL_TERM_ENDDATE = "enddate";

    SQLiteDatabase mDB;

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DBNAME, null, 1);
        mDB = this.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String crt_term_sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TBL_TERM + "(" +
                COL_TERM_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
                COL_TERM_TITLE + " TEXT, " +
                COL_TERM_STARTDATE + " TEXT," +
                COL_TERM_ENDDATE + " TEXT" +
                ")";
        db.execSQL(crt_term_sql);
    }

    public long addTerm(String title, String startdate, String enddate) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COL_TERM_TITLE,title);
        cv.put(COL_TERM_STARTDATE,startdate);
        cv.put(COL_TERM_ENDDATE,enddate);
        return mDB.insert(TBL_TERM,null,cv);
    }

    public Cursor getAllData() {
        return mDB.query(TBL_TERM,null,null,null,null,null,COL_TERM_STARTDATE + " ASC");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }
}
```

The Activity :-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    LinearLayout layout;
    DatabaseHelper myDB;
    Cursor mCsr;
    Context mContext;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        layout = this.findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout);
        mContext = this;
        myDB = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        addSomeData();

        mCsr = myDB.getAllData();
        while (mCsr.moveToNext()) {
            LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
            ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
            long currentID = mCsr.getLong(mCsr.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COL_TERM_ID));
            addtextView(ll,currentID,mCsr.getString(mCsr.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COL_TERM_ID)) + "   ");
            addtextView(ll,currentID,mCsr.getString(mCsr.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COL_TERM_TITLE))+ "   ");
            addtextView(ll,currentID,mCsr.getString(mCsr.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COL_TERM_STARTDATE))+ "   ");
            addtextView(ll, currentID,mCsr.getString(mCsr.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COL_TERM_ENDDATE))+ "   ");
            layout.addView(ll);
        }
    }

    private void addtextView(LinearLayout ll, long tag, String data) {
        TextView current_tv = new TextView(this);
        current_tv.setTag(String.valueOf(tag)); //<<<<<<<<<< SETS THE TAG with current_id
        current_tv.setText(data);
        ll.addView(current_tv);
        current_tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                long id = Long.valueOf((String)v.getTag()); //<<<<<<<<<< RETRIEVES THE id FROM THE TAG
                Toast.makeText(mContext,"You clicked on ID " + String.valueOf(id),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    // JUST TO ADD SOME DATA FOR TESTING (if none exists)
    private void addSomeData() {
        if (DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(myDB.getWritableDatabase(),DatabaseHelper.TBL_TERM) < 1) {
            myDB.addTerm("Term 1","2019-01-01","2019-03-31");
            myDB.addTerm("Term 2","2019-04-01","2019-06-30");
            myDB.addTerm("Term 3","2019-07-01","2019-08-31");
            myDB.addTerm("Term 4","2019-09-01","2019-12-31");
        }
    }
}
```

- Note that if you add/delete/edit rows in a hierarchically lower activity then you'd need to rebuild the views.
- A LinearLayout with horizintal orientation has been added for each row. The primary Linearlayout is set to vertical orientation.

## Alternative (typical solution)

However, simpler to manage (especially regarding updated data) is a ListView. Perhaps consider the following as an alternative.

In the activity's (Main2Activity in this example) layout add a ListView e.g. **activity_main2.xml** is :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Main2Activity">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Terms"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

As you want 3 TextViews (id isn't really user friendly as it means nothing and could even be confusing) per displayed row then another layout for each row of the list e.g. **termlist.xml** :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="6"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/startdate"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/enddate"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The DatabaseHelper DatabaseJelper.java is unchanged.

**MainActivity2.java** (as used as an alternative to MainActivity so that both activities can be checked) :-

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DatabaseHelper myDB;
    ListView mylistview;
    SimpleCursorAdapter sca;
    Cursor mCsr;
    Context mContext;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        mContext = this;
        mylistview = this.findViewById(R.id.listview);
        myDB = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        addSomeData();
        manageListView();
    }

    private void manageListView() {
        mCsr = myDB.getAllData();
        if (sca == null) {
            sca = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                    this,
                    R.layout.termlist,mCsr,
                    new String[]{DatabaseHelper.COL_TERM_TITLE,DatabaseHelper.COL_TERM_STARTDATE,DatabaseHelper.COL_TERM_ENDDATE},
                    new int[]{R.id.title,R.id.startdate,R.id.enddate},
                    0
            );
            mylistview.setAdapter(sca);
            mylistview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    Toast.makeText(mContext,"Your clicked on ID " + String.valueOf(id),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        } else {
            sca.swapCursor(mCsr);
        }
    }

    // JUST TO ADD SOME TEST DATA IF NOE EXISTS
    private void addSomeData() {
        if (DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(myDB.getWritableDatabase(),DatabaseHelper.TBL_TERM) < 1) {
            myDB.addTerm("Term 1","2019-01-01","2019-03-31");
            myDB.addTerm("Term 2","2019-04-01","2019-06-30");
            myDB.addTerm("Term 3","2019-07-01","2019-08-31");
            myDB.addTerm("Term 4","2019-09-01","2019-12-31");
        }
    }

    //ADDED as simply calling manageListView will rebuild the list according to the data
    //  as such when the activity is returned to from another the List is rebuilt
    // (basically the Cursor mCsr is overwritten and then as the SimpleCursorAdapter sca is instantiated
    //  the Cursor is swappped)
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        manageListView();
    }
}
```

## Results

The Fisrt (dynamic TextViews) :-

[image]

The Alternative results in :-

[image]

**In both cases clicking a row results in the id being toasted** (not going to the effort of trying to catch the Toast).

- Both have also been checked out on Android 10